# I am trying to gain the MetaData for Media Player but keep getting a C2228 error in QT

Tags: c++, qt, mp3, metadata, audio-player

I am trying to get the metaData regarding a audioPlayer to output but keep getting the C2228 error and I am struggling to make process past the code below

```
  void Widget::on_lblArtistname_linkActivated(const QString &link)
  {
     player->metaData.composer;
  }
```

what seems to be wrong

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is wrong, [metadata](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtmultimedia/qmediaobject.html#metaData) is a function that takes a QString parameter and returns the metadata associated with that key, you need:

```
QString composer = player->metaData("composer");
```

Comment: void Widget::on_lblSongname_linkActivated(const QString & title)
{
    QString title = player->metaData("title");
}